# Counterintuitive logic in a conditional probability exercise

Tags: combinatorics, conditional-probability

I found this exercise online:

From the list of integers {11,12,13...20} you choose a random one. What is the probability that the chosen number is divisible by 2, under the condition that it is greater than 13.

So my logic was that:
$\Omega$ = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}
A - numbers divisible by 2
B - numbers greater than 13
A = {12,14,16,18,20)
B = {14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
A$\cap$B = {14,16,18,20}
P(A$\cap$B) = 4/10

But the actual answer is:
P(A|B) = P(A$\cap$B) / P(B) = 4/7

I know this is conditional probability but it seems so counterintuitive to me that I can't wrap my head around it.
Can someone please explain to me the logic behind that?

Comment: in $\Omega$ there are are $1/2$ even and $1/2$ odd numbers (in proportion). If you already know that your randomly chosen number is $\geq 14$ you rule out 2 odd numbers out of 5 (11 and 13) and 1 even number (12) out of 5. So your number is ''more likely'' to be even rather than odd.

Comment: The difference is that you've calculated the probability of picking a number which is even **and** more than $13$, not the probability of picking an even number **if** it's more than $13.$ If we're given that we're only picking from numbers more than $13,$ then our sample space shrinks down to only those numbers, of which $4$ of the $7$ are even.